# Switching lastname,firstname to firstname.lastname in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have the below data in a SQL Server 2014 column called EMP_CLASS_10_DESCR

```
OUELLETTE,MAXIME :845800
ANDERSON,ADRIEN :021252
MITRI,NATHALIA :687173
```

What I like to do is have the data represented in the following way by way of a query.

```
MAXIME.OUELLETTE
ADRIEN.ANDERSON
NATHALIA.MITRI
```

What I've done so far is

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':', EMP_CLASS_10_DESCR) 
                     = 0 THEN EMP_CLASS_10_DESCR ELSE LEFT(EMP_CLASS_10_DESCR, CHARINDEX(':', EMP_CLASS_10_DESCR) - 1) END AS FULL_NAME,
```

But all that did was give me the following

```
OUELLETTE,MAXIME
ANDERSON,ADRIEN
MITRI,NATHALIA
```

I still need to flip the names around and replace the , (comma) with a . (period)

Any help will be much appreciated.  I've done some searches but couldn't find anything close.  I'm still very new to SQL Server and just trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PARSENAME`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT CASE 
              WHEN CHARINDEX(':',YourColumn) > 0 
              THEN RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(YourColumn,CHARINDEX(':',YourColumn)-1))) 
              ELSE YourColumn 
           END NewColumn
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT CONCAT(PARSENAME(REPLACE(NewColumn,',','.'),1),'.',PARSENAME(REPLACE(NewColumn,',','.'),2))
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I tried what you suggested and the output is now as follows `MAXIME :845800.OUELLETTE`
`ADRIEN :021252.ANDERSON`
`NATHALIA :687173.MITRI`  i now need to get rid of the :123456 (colon and numeric values in the middle)

Comment: @rasmac I had assumed that the `:845800`  was another column. I updated my answe now

Comment: thanks again but when I try the updated answer I'm now faced with the following error `Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 45
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`

Comment: you my friend are a genius and I have a much better appreciation for SQL Server.  That worked splendidly and much appreciated Lamak.  Thank you so much for your help.